# predicateForEventsWithStartDate doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent, ekeventstore

i'm trying to fetch event from a calendar, and i'm doing it using this method:

```
predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:
```

but if i create a start date like this:

```
NSString *str =@"3/15/1980 9:15 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
```

then i do this:

```
predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:date endDate:endDate calendars:  [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent]];

NSArray *eventArray = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

the eventArray is nil, instead if i use:

```
[NSDate date]
```

find me the events from today to the future, instead with the old date don't work, i have tried also other old date, but the array is always nil...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using predicateForEventsWithStartDate function, it looks like the events returned lies in a time interval of around 4 years (86400*365*4+86400*2). 
Seems like a bug.